# How to add a repeated column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing my homework and I encounter a problem, I have a large matrix, the first column Y002 is a nominal variable, which has 3 levels and encoded as 1,2,3 respectively. The other two columns V96 and V97 are just numeric.

Now, I wanna get a group mean corresponds to the variable Y002. I wrote the code like this

`group = data2.groupby(by=["Y002"]).mean()`

Then I index to get each group mean using

`group1 = group["V96"]`

```
group2 = group["V97"]
```

Now I wanna append this group mean as a new column into the original dataframe, in which each mean matches the corresponding Y002 code(1 or 2 or 3). Actually I tried this code, but it only shows NAN.

```
data2["group1"] = pd.Series(group1, index=data2.index)
```

Hope someone could help me with this, many thanks :)

PS: Hope this makes sense. just like R language, we can do the same thing using

`data2$group1 = with(data2, tapply(V97,Y002,mean))[data2$Y002]`

But how can we implement this in Python and pandas???

Comment: Actually, I am thinking an alternative way, which is count how many 1's, 2's and 3's in the variable Y002, respectively, then write a pandas Series. the problem is how to write a pandas has 502 of 6.54, 320 of 6.75 and 290 of 6.44 to be a new column

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.transform()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your data
# ============================
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y002': np.random.randint(1,4,100), 'V96': np.random.randn(100), 'V97': np.random.randn(100)})
print(df)


       V96     V97  Y002
0  -0.6866 -0.1478     1
1   0.0149  1.6838     2
2  -0.3757  0.9718     1
3  -0.0382  1.6077     2
4   0.3680 -0.2571     2
5  -0.0447  1.8098     3
6  -0.3024  0.8923     1
7  -2.2244 -0.0966     3
8   0.7240 -0.3772     1
9   0.3590 -0.5053     1
..     ...     ...   ...
90 -0.6906  1.5567     2
91 -0.6815 -0.4189     3
92 -1.5122 -0.4097     1
93  2.1969  1.1164     2
94  1.0412 -0.2510     3
95 -0.0332 -0.4152     1
96  0.0656 -0.6391     3
97  0.2658  2.4978     1
98  1.1518 -3.0051     2
99  0.1380 -0.8740     3

# processing
# ===========================
df['V96_mean'] = df.groupby('Y002')['V96'].transform(np.mean)
df['V97_mean'] = df.groupby('Y002')['V97'].transform(np.mean)
df

       V96     V97  Y002  V96_mean  V97_mean
0  -0.6866 -0.1478     1   -0.1944    0.0837
1   0.0149  1.6838     2    0.0497   -0.0496
2  -0.3757  0.9718     1   -0.1944    0.0837
3  -0.0382  1.6077     2    0.0497   -0.0496
4   0.3680 -0.2571     2    0.0497   -0.0496
5  -0.0447  1.8098     3    0.0053   -0.0707
6  -0.3024  0.8923     1   -0.1944    0.0837
7  -2.2244 -0.0966     3    0.0053   -0.0707
8   0.7240 -0.3772     1   -0.1944    0.0837
9   0.3590 -0.5053     1   -0.1944    0.0837
..     ...     ...   ...       ...       ...
90 -0.6906  1.5567     2    0.0497   -0.0496
91 -0.6815 -0.4189     3    0.0053   -0.0707
92 -1.5122 -0.4097     1   -0.1944    0.0837
93  2.1969  1.1164     2    0.0497   -0.0496
94  1.0412 -0.2510     3    0.0053   -0.0707
95 -0.0332 -0.4152     1   -0.1944    0.0837
96  0.0656 -0.6391     3    0.0053   -0.0707
97  0.2658  2.4978     1   -0.1944    0.0837
98  1.1518 -3.0051     2    0.0497   -0.0496
99  0.1380 -0.8740     3    0.0053   -0.0707

[100 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: @user3084591 You are most welcome. Glad that it helped.